# There is a way to take multiple photos without leaving the camera

Tags: angular, cordova, ionic-framework

i created an app to take pictures via cordova i would like to integrate the ability to take multiple pictures without leaving the camera
ES: click on the button, take 10 photos and then upload them
as does whatsapp for example

Comment: use Media Capture Plugin for Multiple Photos: https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/media-capture

Comment: Could you recommend some repository where this function has already been created?

Comment: check this tutorial: https://devdactic.com/ionic-4-media-files-guide/

Comment: this tutorial captures 1 image at a time, I would like to capture 20 images and then send them without leaving the camera

Answer (score 0):

Use Media Capture Plugin it have Limit Options for Multiple Images:

Installation:

> ionic cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-media-capture

> npm install @ionic-native/media-capture

```
import { MediaCapture, MediaFile, CaptureError, CaptureImageOptions, CaptureVideoOptions } from '@ionic-native/media-capture/ngx';


constructor(private mediaCapture: MediaCapture) { }

    
CaptureMultiplePhotos(){
   let options: CaptureImageOptions = { limit: 3 } // pass your limit for images
   this.mediaCapture.captureImage(options)
     .then(
       (data: MediaFile[]) => {
         console.log('Your Multiple Photos Array:', data)
       },
       (err: CaptureError) => console.error(err)
     );
}
```

Comment: I entered the code but it always makes me take one photo at a time.
I shoot and retake or use comes out, I would like to take 20 photos and then click use and load them

Comment: share your code.

Answer (score 0):

.HTML

```
<ion-content [fullscreen]="true">
    <ion-button color="primary" (click)="CaptureMultiplePhotos()">Scatta</ion-button>
</ion-content>
```

.TS

```
import { Component, NgZone } from '@angular/core';
import { MediaCapture, MediaFile, CaptureError, CaptureImageOptions } from '@ionic-native/media-capture/ngx';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-home',
  templateUrl: 'home.page.html',
  styleUrls: ['home.page.scss'],
})
export class HomePage {

  constructor(private mediaCapture: MediaCapture) {}

  CaptureMultiplePhotos(){
    const options: CaptureImageOptions = { limit: 3 }; // pass your limit for images
    this.mediaCapture.captureImage(options)
        .then(
            (data: MediaFile[]) => {
              console.log('Your Multiple Photos Array:', data);
            },
            (err: CaptureError) => console.error(err)
        );
  }
}
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: you can look at the photos of this deprecated app
https://github.com/Surnet/ionic-multi-camera
I would like to create something similar.
Take multiple photos without leaving the camera each time